# How to implement a score driven Copula Model in r

Tags: r, optimization

I want to implement a dynamic copula based on the GAS framework of *Creal et all (2013)*. I'm starting with a bivariate Student's [image] copula and considering that the updating equation for the parameter of the copula is:

[image]

where
[image]
is the score of the log density of the copula, I derive this score for the [image] copula (like *Ayala and Blazsek* https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/1351847X.2018.1464488?src=recsys, here there is also the copula density function):

[image]

My problem is that when I try to optimize the Maximum Likelihood parameter estimates don't converge in any way. I don't know if it is a problem related to the constraints on the parameters or if it is wrong the cycle that I inserted in the function to determine [image]. 
This is the code

```
loglik_t = function(param) {
  dfactor = numeric()
  rho = numeric()
  score = numeric()
  tau =  cor(u_sp, u_eu, method = "kendall")
  dfactor[1] = tau
  tu = qt(u_sp, nu)  
  tv = qt(u_eu, nu)   
  omega = param[1]
  dA = exp(param[2])
  dB = exp(param[3])/(1 + exp(param[3]))
  x2 = log(gamma((nu + 2)/2)) +  log(gamma(nu/2)) - log(digamma((nu + 1)/2))
  LL = 0
  for (i in 1:length(u_sp)){
    rho[i] = sin((pi/2)*dfactor[i])
    #log-likelihood for observation i
    x1 = -0.5*log(1 - rho[i]^2)
    x3 =((-nu + 2)/2)*log(1 + (tu[i]^2+tv[i]^2-2*rho[i]*tu[i]*tv[i])/(nu*(1-rho[i]^2)))
    x4 = ((-nu + 1)/2)*log(1 + tu[i]^2/nu) + ((-nu + 1)/2)*log(1 + tv[i]^2/nu)
    c_t = x1 + x2 + x3 - x4
    LL = LL + c_t

    #GAS dynamic
    x1score = rho[i]/(1 - rho[i]^2)
    x2score = (nu + 2)/(rho[i]^2 - 1)
    x3score = rho[i]*(tu[i]^2 + tv[i]^2) - (rho[i]^2 + 1)*tu[i]*tv[i]
    x4score = tu[i]^2 + tv[i]^2 - 2*rho[i]*tu[i]*tv[i] - nu*(rho[i]^2 - 1)
    score[i] = x1score + x2score*(x3score/x4score)

    dfactor[i + 1] = omega + dA*score[i] + dB*rho[i]
  }

  return(list(LL, rho, score))
}

n = length(u_sp)

qlogL.hat = -10^10
for (i in (1:10)) {

    # Initial values

    start.theta = runif(3, min = 0.01, max = 0.9999)



    qml.fit = optim(start.theta, fn = function(x) loglik_t(x)[[1]], 
                    hessian = TRUE, method = "L-BFGS-B", 
                    lower = c(-2,0.0001,0.0001),
                    upper = c(0.9999, 0.999, 0.9999),
                    control = list(trace = 1, fnscale = -1))




    if (qml.fit$value > qlogL.hat) {
        theta.hat = qml.fit$par
        inv.J.hat = solve(-qml.fit$hessian/(n-1))
        jacobian.hat = pracma:: jacobian(loglik_t1,theta.hat)   
        I.hat = (t(jacobian.hat) %*% jacobian.hat)/(n-1)
        sd.hat = sqrt(diag(inv.J.hat %*% I.hat %*% inv.J.hat)/(n-1))
        qlogL.hat = qml.fit$value
        i
    }

}
```